# Map object has no len() in Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have this Python tool written by someone else to flash a certain microcontroller, but he has written this tool for Python 2.6 and I am using Python 3.3.

So, most of it I got ported, but this line is making problems:

```py
data = map(lambda c: ord(c), file(args[0], 'rb').read())
```

The `file` function does not exist in Python 3 and has to be replaced with `open`. But then, a function which gets `data` as an argument causes an exception:

```
TypeError: object of type 'map' has no len()
```

But what I see so far in the documentation is, that `map` has to join iterable types to one big iterable, am I missing something?

What do I have to do to port this to Python 3?

Comment: That's odd, `map` objects should be iterable. Can you post the full traceback?

Comment: You are right, the actuall error message is:
_TypeError: object of type 'map' has no len()_

Comment: FYI, there's no reason to call len on a map object, since the underlying object has the same length.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

In Python 3, [`map`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map) returns an iterator. If your function expects a list, the iterator has to be explicitly converted, like this:

```
data = list(map(...))
```

And we can do it simply, like this

```
with open(args[0], "rb") as input_file:
    data = list(input_file.read())
```

`rb` refers to read in binary mode. So, it actually returns the bytes. So, we just have to convert them to a list.

Quoting from the [`open`'s docs](http://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open),

> Python distinguishes between binary and text I/O. Files opened in
>   binary mode (including 'b' in the mode argument) return contents as
>   bytes objects without any decoding.

Comment: THis works better, thanks. But as I am reading a binary file, input_file.read() retruns a byte-array and ord causes an exception, as it expects a string