# Gensim 1.0.1 on Python 3.5 TypeError: object of type 'map' has no len()?

Tags: python, python-3.x, anaconda, gensim

I installed Python 3.5 using Anaconda and gensim 1.0.1 (supports Python 3) using pip. I got the following error when running gensim:

```
Exception in thread Thread-61:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/mac/anaconda/lib/python3.5/threading.py", line 914, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/Users/mac/anaconda/lib/python3.5/threading.py", line 862, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/Users/mac/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/gensim/models/word2vec.py", line 838, in job_producer
    sentence_length = self._raw_word_count([sentence])
  File "/Users/mac/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/gensim/models/word2vec.py", line 755, in _raw_word_count
    return sum(len(sentence) for sentence in job)
  File "/Users/mac/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/gensim/models/word2vec.py", line 755, in <genexpr>
    return sum(len(sentence) for sentence in job)
TypeError: object of type 'map' has no len()
```

The code causing this error is from [node2vec](https://github.com/aditya-grover/node2vec). I am porting it to Python 3 but got this error.

I know that in Python 3, len(map) causes error, does it mean Gensim 1.0.1 does not support Python 3 although [pip website](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/gensim) says it supports? Or are there some hidden settings?

Anyone has any idea what is wrong? Thanks.

Comment: You're either running a Python script that was written for Python 2.x or you're explicitly passing a map object somewhere where you shouldn't. From the traceback alone, one cannot see what the case is.

Comment: What I'm trying to get to is that you need to include the code you're executing.

Comment: The code is from [node2vec](https://github.com/aditya-grover/node2vec). I am porting it to python 3 but got this error.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Map object has no len() in Python 3.3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21572840/map-object-has-no-len-in-python-3-3)

Comment: @ŁukaszRogalski I know about the error in Python 3. What I asked is about Gensim, because this version supports Python 3.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Gensim supports Python 3, of course. It is your (or node2vec's) responsibility to supply `Word2Vec()` with an iterable of your sentences.

In this case, you have to pass it an iterable that contains walks - where each walk is a list of vertices:

```
walks = [list(map(str, walk)) for walk in walks] # convert each vertex id to a string
model = Word2Vec(walks, ...)
```

Comment: It would make more sense if Gensim converted `map` to `list` itself, that would be real python 3 supported. But I guess this answer also suggests an alternative solution for end user.